# GLPK Java Crashes on GLPK.new_intArray

Tags: java, dll, native, glpk

There is something weird happening in my code. I made a function to dynamically create a MIP problem to GLPK resolve. The problem is that in some part of the code JVM crashes.

After debug I found that the crash occur exactly when I create an intArray (GLPK.new_intArray). In the source code this function call GLPKJNI.new_intArray(nelements) which corresponds to a native function from DLL file.

As this function return a pointer to a new intArray, I thought it could be a memory problem and so I increased the size of Tomcat heap, but it didn't helped.

Thoughts?

Info:

```
Eclipse - 20130614-0229 (KEPLER)
JRE - 1.7.0_45
GLPK - 4.54
Tomcat - 7.0.47
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for help. The problem was in the creation of my problem.
I am using loops to create the columns and rows and the generation of indexes (derivated from i, j, rowSize and columnSize) was wrong. After thinking a couple of hours the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the cause was different.

If you are using `GLPK.new_intArray(nbElements)` in a loop, you must invoke the method `GLPK.delete_intArray(array)` after you are done (before next iteration).